# How to deal with that when the processRecords is failed in AWS KCL?

Tags: amazon-kcl

I am creating an application with nodejs based on KCL. in the `processRecords` function, I tried to send the records which I get from kinesis to the web service with http request. But when the web service is not available, the http request will be failed. I want to KCL stop to get records from kinesis and send an alert to pagerduty.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Providing this more as a general strategy instead of specific code:

In case you aren't already, make sure you've setup a good [retry policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) with [exponential backoff](https://www.awsarchitectureblog.com/2015/03/backoff.html) in case of errors - this will handle most temporary problems.

In your case, you probably want a 'retry forever' type policy, and fire off your pagerduty alert when the number of retries crosses some threshold you define (ie: numRetries==30 or something).